# powershell to bulk remove certain character(s) from many filenames within multiple subfolders

Tags: powershell

I've researched this issue and have perused the knowledge base here. I did find a few topics that dabbled in removing certain characters in a file/folder name via PowerShell. Unfortunately, trying to do the below cmdlet resulted in the following error.

```
cmd: Get-Item * | ForEach-Object {Rename-Item $_ ($_.Name -replace "%", "")}
error: rename-item: Source and destination path must be different
```

There are many thousands of files. I'm trying to remove `%` and `#` symbols from any and all filenames within many subfolders.

Example: Before

```
FileName%1%#1.doc
```

after

```
FileName11.doc
```

Comment: Can you add the complete stack trace ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use cmd but powershell. Here is the correct syntax from your example:)

```
Get-Item * | ForEach-Object {Rename-Item $_ -NewName ($_.name -replace '#','' -replace '%','')}
```

Comment: After trying it out, I still encounter the below error in PowerShell:


         Rename-Item : Source and destination path must be different.
At line:1 char:30
+ Get-Item * | ForEach-Object {Rename-Item $_ -NewName ($_.name -replace '#','' -r ...
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (G:\WESTWICKE\Sy...n Loren's Files:String) [Rename-Item]
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: try adding `-Force` parameter to the rename-item